# this._id is not accessible to Iron controller in Meteor js. How to get the id?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have this in my `dashboard.html`

```
{{#each todos}}
  <li class="list-group-item">
      {{ task }}
      <button class="delete"> Delete</button>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

and in the controller `dashboard.js` I have this

```
DashboardController.events({
  'click .delete': function () {
    Meteor.call('ToDos.delete',this._id);
  }
});
```

Without Iron Controller I can access the id of the collection in the event using `this._id` but with this setup it has a null value. Any ideas how to get the id of the collection todo in the controller?

Comment: what did you get with `this.data();`?

Comment: @Ethaan I got this value Object {todos: LocalCollection.Cursor}. I tried this.data().id, this.data()._id, this.todos._id, this.todos.id its all undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: try with this.data().todos you should know that you are accession the data from the iron route not from the template instance, for example try with console.log(this.params)

Comment: @Ethaan I got this value LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, _selectorId: undefined, matcher: Minimongo.Matcher, skip: undefined…}. But how can I get the id of record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the follow.

```
DashboardController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'layout',
    data: function () { return SomeCollection.findOne(); },
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('someCollection') }
});

DashboardController.events({
  'click .delete': function () {
   console.log(this.data())
   console.log(this.data()._id)//not sure if this works.
    Meteor.call('ToDos.delete',this.data());
  }
});
```

The key here its that we don't need the `{{#each}}`, you should use the data function to populate the template with data.

if you do the follow it will work.

```
Template.example.events({
'click .delete': function () {
       console.log(this.data()) //undefined
       console.log(this._id)//id
        Meteor.call('ToDos.delete',this._id);
      }
})
```

Comment: thanks for our answer. when you say we don't need the {{#each}} how will my dashboard.html look like?

Comment: look what you `{{#each todos}}` do its get a simple cursor of some `collection`? correct? some `collection.find();` well you can do the same with `data:function(){return collection.find()}` so with that the todos helpers its don't needed and the `this.data()` will return the actual context of data (sorry for the super bad english)